# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range with elements in the array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello again the community,

I have a problem with an array that I made
This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var allWords : [String] = []
    
    func startGame() {
        if let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start", withExtension: "txt") {
            if let startWords = try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL) {
                allWords = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                return
            }
        }
        
        if allWords.isEmpty {
            allWords = ["silkworm"]
        }
        
        fatalError("Could not load start.txt from bundle.")
    }
    
    var body: some View { 
        VStack{ 
            Text(String(allWords[1]))
                .onAppear(perform: startGame) 
                .font(.system(size: 30)) 
                .frame(width: 1000, height: 75) 
                .background(Rectangle() 
                .foregroundColor(.white)) 
                .border(Color.black, width: 1) 
        } 
    }
```

I have a fatal error on the line Text(String(allWords[1]))
Which tell me that I'm out of range but when I try to print the size of the array with for example allWords.count it tells me that I have 11 elements.

Is it a problem with the declaration of my array ?

Thank you in advance everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake. When the view is rendered the first time the array is empty.

It's highly recommended to get **never** elements of an array by index subscription in the rendering area of the view unless it's guaranteed that the array contains the item at requested index.

Make a *safe check* and the `String` initializer is redundant

```
Text(allWords.count > 1 ? allWords[1] : "")
```

A `List` or `ForEach` expression is safe because the body is not being executed if the array is empty.\

On the other hand the `if allWords.isEmpty` check is pointless because **you** know whether the file is empty or not at **compile time**.

Answer (score 0):

You called the function **StartGame()** inside **onAppear**. In this case **Text** load first then calls your function. So While loading **Text(String(allWords[1]))**, **allWords** is **Nil**

You should handle it as `Text(allWords.count > 1 ? allWords[1] : "YourDefaultText")`

**OnAppear** is a view that triggers action when this view appears.